# Windows 10 not opening after dual boot with ubuntu 16.10

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, 16.10

I just installed ubuntu in dual boot with windows 10. Everything is fine except that I am unable to access Windows 10. Everytime I select windows 10 in the grub menu,screen turns black for few seconds and it shows grub menu again.
I've tried it more than 10 times but it repeats the same thing again. But ubuntu is working fine. How can I use my windows 10 again ??

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu in legacy mode?

Comment: Can you boot Windows from the EFI menu (some function key at power on to select OS/device to boot?  Is secure boot enabled or disabled? And just to be sure, is Windows 10 installed in UEFI mode (likely if preinstalled).

Comment: @user68186  Yeah...  I guess its legacy mode

Comment: Search this forum for similar problems. You will find solution using *boot repair*.

Comment: @ubfan1 No.. It wasnt preinstalled..

Comment: @user68186  I tried seaching for similar problems but it was of no help..  Can you plz give me the link to the already asked question or some search keywords through which i'd find the solution??

Comment: Try https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I tried bootrepair but it didnt help :|

Comment: If you have already used boot repair could you provide us with the boot info summary